# Rails: passing variables in URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, variables, routes

I'm trying to access a resource in my rails app that I want to populate with information based on the variable in the URL. Given the URL:

```
someapp.com/resources/variable/resource
```

I would like to pass the `variable` to Rails to add elements to `resource`. Is there any quick re-routing way of achieving this? Or is it insanely complicated?

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No part of this should be "insanely complicated", but it's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish.

You could try adding a route with a variable segment:

```
get "/resources/:variable/resource" => "controller#action"
```

Then, in your controller, access `params[:variable]`.

---

If your already have a resource defined, you can add an additional "member" route via the following:

```
resource :resources do
  get :resource, on: member

  # or

  member do
    get :resource
  end
end
```

Either of the previous will allow your controller to route `/resources/:resource_id/resource` to the resources controller's `resource` action.

Comment: That's giving me clues, yeah. But if the `resources/resource` already exist it doesn't seem to work. In my `routes.rb` I have already `resources :resources`.

Comment: See my update. Also, `resources` is a very bad name for a resource. Your resources should have specific names, matching the things they represent.

Comment: Ah, that helped me so much! Cheers. And my resources aren't named that, I just used it for the example. Which ended up being far more complicated than it should have.